# Regex for maximum 4 digit with or without decimal followed by N Or S

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that allows a total of 5 Characters |Number followed by N or N.

prepared regex:

```
/^\h*(?:(?:\d|[1-9 ]{1,4})?)[NSns]$/gm
```

Problem statement:**I am not able to add fraction point to regex**

Valid Output:

```
1S
2N
1 S
1212S
1212s
1212N
1212n
1212n
121 n
121 N
121 s
121 S
12.22S
1.2N
12.2S
12.3 N
```

Invalid outputs:

```
123456S
12343S
122.122
12334.12
```

Comment: `\h` is not supported by JS RegExp.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew its supported here https://regex101.com/

Comment: No, `\h`  in JS regex is not the same as `\h` in PCRE regex. Just use it in code and you will understand.

Comment: tested in the typescript and its working....

Comment: Try `^(?!(?:\D*\d){5})\s*\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*[NSns]$`, see https://regex101.com/r/8pLKgT/1 (and if you still think `\h` works in JS, replace spaces with `\h` in that regex and you will see)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it's working as per the expectations.can u plz post this as answer so i can accept this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i want to allow 100. 5N this space after fraction part into above exp.can u guide me ?

Comment: Change `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` to `(?:\.\s*\d{1,2})?`, see https://regex101.com/r/8pLKgT/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i want to allow 2AN in the above regix.2A with N or S at ennding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!(?:\D*\d){5})\s*\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*[NSns]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8pLKgT/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!(?:\D*\d){5})` - no five digits allowed in the string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces (use `[^\S\r\n]*` if you need to stay on the same line)
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of `.` and one or two digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[NSns]` - `N`, `S`, `n` or `s`
- `$` - end of string.